# Volatile variable doesnt change in onResponse method

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to read response and then to set it in global variable so I could use it in activity. The request is in separated class. I have tried in activity class where I have set volatile static variables, but it didn't changed.

In Activity :

```
private void posalji(String name, String jmb){
        SendData sendData = new SendData(getApplicationContext(), Constants.FIRSTtimeREQUEST_URL);
        HashMap<String, String> mapa = new HashMap<>();
        mapa.put("name", name);
        mapa.put("jmb", jmb);
        mapa.put("phone", pNumber);
        mapa.put("mac_address", getMacAddress());
        sendData.setDataMap(mapa);
        sendData.sendData();

        if(sendData.isSend()) {
            //do something
        }else{
           //do something
        }
    }
```

In class SendData :

```
public void sendData() {
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                setSend(true);
                setRetrievedData(parseHTML(response));
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                setSend(false);
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Iterator it = dataMap.entrySet().iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                    params.put(pair.getKey().toString(), pair.getValue().toString());
                    it.remove();
                }
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

I need to change value of `Boolean` and to be able to read it in activity.
Sorry if the question is trivial. I'm new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

in class SendData declare a static variable and use it to store the result of senData method:

```
private static boolean resultOk;
```

change the return type of sendData to boolean and change `setSend(true);` to `resultOk = true;`

In the end of the method: `return resultOk;`

in activity just call the method directly `if(SendData.sendData()) {}`

Comment: unfortunately it didnt worked, for some reason value didnt changed